# How to edit an ODOO template (which was customized using website builder) by inheriting it in my module?

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-website

I have done some editing to the home page of ODOO website using the EDIT button at the top-left corner. After some time, I have decided to make some changes to the Home page by inheriting the XML template to my module and done the changes in the template. But these changes are not reflecting in the web page. I have faced this problem many times on customizing the template with the website builder of ODOO. I have noticed that the changes are directly applied to the XML view which can be seen at `Settings->Technical Settings->User Interface->Views` and this is not changed to the previous state even the module is upgraded. Is there any way I could customize the template by inheriting it in my module in this case? The customizations work for all templates for which I have done no editing in the website builder.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When a view/template is saved through the website editor it marks, if exists, the related `ir.model.data` record as `noupdate = True` to not apply changes to the view if a module is updated.

To do the change you need to **remove the noupdate** value of that record on the ir.model.data model table.

Comment: select * from ir_model_data where module = 'academy'

Answer (score 0):

**Update your theme**

Since XML files are only loaded when you install the theme, you will have to force reloading every time you make changes on an xml file.

To do that, click on the Upgrade button in the module’s page.

[image]

Comment: I have upgraded the module and all the changes work perfectly for views except customized from the frontend EDIT button. The problem occurs only in the home page template which I had edited from the front end.